# Should I always check if [[NSArray alloc] init…] returns nil?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, collections, nsarray

Should I always check if `[[NSArray alloc] init…]` (or with any other collection class) returns `nil`? The Apple docs say that objects may return `nil` if allocation or initialisation fails. I don't know when initialising may fail with `NSArray`, but I guess that allocation may fail with insufficient memory. And because I'm developing for iOS, that may become a regular problem. Do I have to about that and check *every* time I want to create a new array, or will my app fail because of memory constraints (assuming worst-case situation, of course) and checking for `nil` is just a waste of cycles?

Currently, I'm only checking when I allocate a mutable collection with a large predetermined capacity (e.g. `[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 1000]`) or an immutable collection with lots of objects (over a thousand).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with `NSArray`. `NSArray` is a linked list using structs, so it does not `malloc` much behind the scenes. Checking for nil, at least with `NSArray` is rather pointless.

However, if you were using a collection class like `CCArray`, from cocos2d, for example then checking for nil with a large array could be beneficial.

Still, the size of a pointer on iOS is 8 bytes, and even a C-Array of 1000 elements is only 8 KB of RAM. In most cases, you won't be using enough memory to the point where you will run out.

Also note that if you come to the point where your application is running low on memory, there are many delegate methods that you can register to to be warned about this and fix it.

Comment: @jrturton I think you meant to comment on my question. Yes, I realise now how pointless it is, but I think my intentions are nevertheless clear. I edited the question. :-p

Comment: Really? It's not an object?! :-o Do you have any sources?

Comment: _"Also note that if you come to the point where your application is running low on memory, there are many delegate methods that you can register to to be warned about this and fix it."_ That's why I said "worst-case situation". ;-)

Comment: NSArray is an object class (actually a cluster of classes behind the scenes). An array may be backed by a linked list, or it may be backed by a C array or some other collection—it's an implementation detail that's deliberately hidden from you.

Comment: 1000 8-byte elements is 8 kilobytes, not 8 megabytes.

Comment: @RandyMarsh No, NSArray is an object, but under the hood, most implementations you will be dealing with will be a linked list, especially a NSMutableArray. It contains one element as the head/tail, each of which hold a reference to the next element in a list. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_List

Comment: Why [[NSArray alloc] init] is pointless? Anyways, you won't benefit from even checking the result of arrayWithCapacity. Apple docs say that it doesn't actually allocate that much memory, it just prepares some internal structures to make things even more optimal.

Comment: @H2CO3 `[NSArray new]` is pointless because `NSArray` is immutable. It cannot be changed, so its just an empty array, which is better described by nil.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just thought you called the initialization itself pointless...

Comment: The size of a pointer on iOS is currently 4 bytes. However, it may change in the future if Apple changes architectures (e.g. to a 64-bit chip.)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: an empty set is not the same as a null pointer. There are legitimate situations where one needs to distinguish (e.g. "valid-but-empty data" vs. "invalid data.")

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan true, but in most situations, there is no difference, as you can send a message to nil in objc without any chance of an exception being raised.

Comment: Depends on the message. Messages returning structures or scalar values with `sizeof(T) < sizeof(id)` have different semantics.